# Why does this PHP tracking pixel not working correctly?

Tags: php, gif

I'm working on setting up a simple pixel tracking script with PHP, and the below technically works, but when I look at the inspector in Safari I get the following warning (1by1.gif is a 42B gif):

> esource interpreted as document but
>   transferred with MIME type image/gif.

```
header("Content-type: image/gif");
header("Content-Length: 42");
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/1by1.gif");
// do tracking stuff below here
```

I've looked at other tracking pixels, and they all show in the inspector as if they are an actual image, even with the .php extension. Any ideas how to fix that warning?

**EDIT:**

I tried doing the following and I get the same warning:

```
header("Content-type: image/gif");
$img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents("/path/to/1by1.gif"));
imagegif($img);
```

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: Apache, although I'm also using CloudFlare and the header returns as: Server:cloudflare-nginx.

Comment: Just to be safe, why don't you use `filesize` instead of a literal 42? Also I'd replace `echo file_get_contents` with `readfile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is interesting. If I remove the content-length and just use the following, it appears to work perfectly. Anyone know why that might be?

```
header("Content-type: image/gif");
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/1by1.gif");
// do tracking stuff below here
```

Comment: I've added an answer with a hypothesis.

Comment: If you type the URL in [viewheaders.com](http://viewheaders.com/) does the length show up? Does `Transfer-Encoding`?

Comment: instead of `echo file_get_contents` you'd probably be better offwith `readfile`

Answer (score 1):

You could write `1x1.gif` (or some other made up name) in your HTML source and then have Apache actually serve the PHP script. You can do this with `.htaccess` with something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^1x1\.gif$ tracking_script.php [NC,L]
```

This way Safari sees the `gif` extension and won't complain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't complaining about the extension as I've seen many other tracking pixels use .php with no problems.

Comment: I upvoted not because it answers the OPs question, but because it's a good addition to the solution. (Apache specific though)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a puzzled. Function file_get_contents() is for getting content from a text file. What is your intend here? The function returns the content as string or false. Your echo statement essentially transfers that result which is correctly interpreted as document and not a gif.

**Update**: Took me a while to even reproduce this and see the warning. Echoing the file_get_contents() shows indeed the gif in the browser, so does a simple include() which also shows the warning. Does this warning causes you any trouble or is this just for a beauty contest? I can only speculate that the Safari's Inspector is a little picky. The same tool in Chrome does not show a warning.

Comment: I thought this was somewhat odd as well, but this is just how I saw several say how to do it. How would you do it differently? I realize this method isn't working right, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly (hence the question here).

Comment: @Adrian: file_get_contents will work just fine with images so long as the `Content-type` header is correct.

Comment: I never did anything like this. I only think at binary levels. file_get_contents returns a string or false. If you echo that result you submit a document. If you submit that document as image/gif then this is wrong. Browser tend to be sloppy and forgiving. The Safari Inspector notices the wrong type, though.

Comment: @Adrian I'm not sure what you're getting at. PHP strings are just character arrays, they can store chr(0) or anything else. Some string-related functions are not binary-safe, but file_get_contents is. What's wrong with using it to output images?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with that. It never occurred to me to output an image as a string with file_get_contents when an include does the same. However, Safari Inspector is complaining in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents("/path/to/1by1.gif"));
imagegif($img);
```

This code

1. Reads in a GIF image
2. Passes the image bytes to GD
3. Asks GD to *write a new image*.

Many things could go wrong here.  For example, writing the image back out *might not* produce the same exact stream of bytes, maybe more, maybe less.  This could make your `Content-Length` header invalid, and browsers don't like it when you lie about such stuff.  Or maybe there's a Notice or Warning in one of the lines, which would be emitted as content before the GIF data.  That would certainly *look* like a "document" instead of as image data to Webkit.

Serving the file through `file_get_contents` / `include` / `echo` eliminates the filter-through-GD step.  If the code works properly without that step, the error was somewhere there.